# Lock MobaXTerm (SSH) tab against changes/editing?

Tags: mobaxterm

(a) is it possible to lock MobaXTerm (SSH) tab against changes/editing?
... and,
(b) is it possible to preview large/egregious paste into SSH tab?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to enable the prompt within the MobaXterm settings for the 2nd one